# Null Pointer Exception in CodeNameone

Tags: codenameone

I would like to apply css to my codename one application, I have downloaded cn1css-ant-task.jar from git hub and put in my lib directory and I applied css to my app, everything is working fine but after some time I got an error. [image]

Comment: FYI you should embed the stack into the question and not include it as an image and that's not a null pointer exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception you are getting from the CSS processor is "unsupported property": `Overflow`.

Don't use `overflow` in the CSS used with Codename One. Notice that you **can't** just get an arbitrary CSS off the internet and use it.